# 2 different SVG path animations animate in the wrong way

Tags: html, xml, svg, path, jquery-animate

i started working with SVG not so long ago and i cant wrap my head around why this works differently. I have a couple of SVG's and i am trying to shape one into the other. In this example (i just pulled out the code that is bothering me) i have 2 path objects moving into the same spot. But one just appears and dissapears, while the other is mooving along the path.

I want to achieve the moving animation like the object below. Is there a problem with the number of points? Because i tried an example of adding "virtual points" (more points with the same number) to match the nubmer of points but still the same thing happens.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening, and maybe shed the light on what im doing wrong?
Here is the example of code:

HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 363 356" xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 0 0 363 356">
<g id="hi_orb_orange">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="149.73" y1="104.66" x2="214.4" y2="104.66" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0526 0.3685 -0.3877 1.1076 9.673 -66.0063)">
  <animate attributeName="x1" values="149.73;227.736" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  <animate attributeName="y1" values="104.66;283.898" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  <animate attributeName="x2" values="214.4;301.366" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  <animate attributeName="y2" values="104.66;283.898" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  <stop offset="0.04" class="s7"/>
  <stop offset="1" class="s8"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st1" d="M194.8 128.9c-4.2 12-22.8 16.3-41.6 9.7 -18.8-6.6-30.6-21.6-26.5-33.6s22.8-16.3 41.6-9.7C187.1 101.9 199 117 194.8 128.9z">

<animate attributeName="d" values="M194.8 128.9c-4.2 12-22.8 16.3-41.6 9.7 -18.8-6.6-30.6-21.6-26.5-33.6s22.8-16.3 41.6-9.7C187.1 101.9 199 117 194.8 128.9z;
M274.3 193.9c-5.8 16.5-23.5 18.8-40.9 12.8 -17.4-6.1-37.4-37.7-31.6-54.2 5.8-16.5 19.6-17.1 37-11C256.2 147.6 280.1 177.4 274.3 193.9z;
M194.8 128.9c-4.2 12-22.8 16.3-41.6 9.7 -18.8-6.6-30.6-21.6-26.5-33.6s22.8-16.3 41.6-9.7C187.1 101.9 199 117 194.8 128.9z" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

</path>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="88.44" y1="-61.73" x2="153.12" y2="-61.73" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0526 -0.3685 -0.3877 -1.1076 9.673 199.3584)">
  <animate attributeName="x1" values="88.44;227.736;88.44" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  <animate attributeName="y1" values="-61.73;283.898;-61.73" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  <animate attributeName="x2" values="153.12;301.366;153.12" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  <animate attributeName="y2" values="-61.73;283.898;-61.73" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  <stop offset="0.04" class="s7"/>
  <stop offset="1" class="s8"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st2" d="M194.8 211.3c-4.2-12-22.8-16.3-41.6-9.7 -18.8 6.6-30.6 21.6-26.5 33.6 4.2 12 22.8 16.3 41.6 9.7C187.1 238.3 199 223.3 194.8 211.3z">

<animate attributeName="d" values="M194.8 211.3c-4.2-12-22.8-16.3-41.6-9.7 -18.8 6.6-30.6 21.6-26.5 33.6 4.2 12 22.8 16.3 41.6 9.7C187.1 238.3 199 223.3 194.8 211.3z;
M274.3 193.9c-5.8 16.5-23.5 18.8-40.9 12.8 -17.4-6.1-37.4-37.7-31.6-54.2 5.8-16.5 19.6-17.1 37-11C256.2 147.6 280.1 177.4 274.3 193.9z;
M194.8 211.3c-4.2-12-22.8-16.3-41.6-9.7 -18.8 6.6-30.6 21.6-26.5 33.6 4.2 12 22.8 16.3 41.6 9.7C187.1 238.3 199 223.3 194.8 211.3z" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

</path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here is the fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/16syyazs/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please add a fiddle so we can help you?

Comment: Hey, added fiddle to the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to animate smoothly (i.e. interpolate) all animations must contain the same number and type of animations.

```
<animate attributeName="d" values="
M194.8 128.9c-4.2 12  -22.8 16.3-41.6 9.7  -18.8-6.6-30.6-21.6-26.5-33.6s22.8-16.3 41.6-9.7C187.1 101.9 199 117 194.8 128.9z;
M274.3 193.9c-5.8 16.5-23.5 18.8-40.9 12.8 -17.4-6.1-37.4-37.7-31.6-54.2 5.8-16.5 19.6-17.1 37-11C256.2 147.6 280.1 177.4 274.3 193.9z;
M194.8 128.9c-4.2 12  -22.8 16.3-41.6 9.7  -18.8-6.6-30.6-21.6-26.5-33.6s22.8-16.3 41.6-9.7C187.1 101.9 199 117 194.8 128.9z" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

If I line up the animations above I can see the top and bottom values have an s but the middle one does not. There may be other problems along the same lines.

Comment: Question then. What would be the correct way to solve this?  Lets say to draw 1 object. Save it to SVG, then change the object into object number 2. Save it to SVG then apply animate to the first one to animate into the second one?   Of course, leaveing the same number and the same order of points?

Comment: And i noticed that, yes. The second line has an S, and there are 3 points missing. What would be the best way to solve this? To make new SVG shapes and watch out for number and order of points/curves? Or is there any way i could simply change the code to allign it somehow?

Comment: The best/only way to solve this would be to make them all the same. How you do that is up to you.